# Lambda based Application on AWS marketplace

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-architecture, aws-marketplace

I have the application containing Lambda function, API gateway, and Dynamodb Table. I want to place complete package in AWS marketplace but not as a SaaS product.

I want to install this package on customer side.

For example - An application, having an lambda function which triggers by dynamoDb table change, also have a api gateway. This application works fine at my end. I want to publish this complete package on marketplace but not as a saas product. I want that this complete package get deployed on customer's AWS instance. But I think my product is not an AMI product or SaaS as well. If you have any solution that how to list a lambda based app on marketplace.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, For example - An application, having an lambda function which triggers by dynamoDb table change, also have a api gateway. This application works fine at my end. I want to publish this complete package on marketplace but not as a saas product. I want that this complete package get deployed on customer's AWS instance.
But I think my product is not an AMI product or SaaS as well. 
If you have any solution that how to list a lambda based app on marketplace.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sorry for that as I am new to community. I will keep in mind for future. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can monetize an API using api gateways marketplace integration. But this requires you run and manage the application.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/monetize-your-apis-in-aws-marketplace-using-api-gateway/

But AWS marketplace doesn't currently support what you need.

Answer (score 0):

AWS CloudFormation can suffice your requirement. From Marketplace you can launch a CloudFormation template which internally can create an instance, lambda etc. And once these resources are created, customer can use it.

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/